# Sum rows with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

The following is an example of what I have to work with.

Sample data :

```
 ID  RANK
---------
 1    2
 1    3
 2    4
 2    1
 3    2
 2    3
 4    2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec3a1/2)

I am trying to combine the rows with like `ID`s and `sum` the `RANK`s for these `ID`s into a single row:

```
ID  SUM(rank)
1      5
2      8
3      2
4      2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sum` aggregate function together with the `group by` clause:

```
select [ID]
     , sum([RANK])
from [STUFF]
group by [ID]
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec3a1/4)